# How to use jQuery Flexigrid with php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I wan to mde flexigirid table; My data which are not comes directly into the database because I put them into the array after that ı put them some htlm tables. know ı want to use jQuery Flexigrid ;how can ı start ? ı have to start from scratch;Can u show me a way...or is there any way make like flexigirid table?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at http://www.datatables.net/ it's a pretty good plugin :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert any static table into a flexigrid with just one line.

$(tableindentifier).flexigrid();